# How to only allow connections between host and guest and vice-versa in virt-manager?

Tags: linux, networking, virt-manager

I thought that creating a virtual network interface using the virt-manager GUI in mode `Isoleted` would work, but it only allows me to ping from host to guest, not the other way around. Also note that there is no built-in `Host-only` mode like in Virtual Box.

So far I have not been able to find a detailed guide that doesn't assume the reader is a network expert and either

1. Shows the configuration on virt-manager step by step
2. Lists and explains the linux commands expected to create the desired interface